# ASP.net 5 Website Preview template missing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, templates, web, asp.net-core-mvc

I am following an ASP.net Tutorial
Under ASP.net5 preview templates the tutorial video has website template 
while my Visual studio shows Web application template
is there any solution to this issue
thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The video is using older versions. So find an updated video, or muddle through and expect things to not work because namespaces have changed.